# Why is the print css acting up in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, printing

I have a print css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

on a calendar page it doesn't load correctly in IE (older versions of 8 and back). However, if I go to another calendar page -> print preview -> return to the first calendar -> and view again the print.css seems to load fine.

Any known cause for this? or is this just IE being... well... IE?

Comment: Make sure your html is valid. There is probably something causing IE not to load the stylesheet.

Comment: It loads it about 95% of the time. Even then it "mostly" loads it. Everything is formatting for printing except for text size.

Comment: Could it just be a caching issue?  I've occasionally had problems getting print styles to trigger right after I make changes.

Comment: if you want to see what I'm looking at: http://www.chattahoocheetech.edu/calendar/fall2011/

Comment: Print preview in IE. The page doesn't look the same everytime.

Comment: more info: If i change the zoom to any level (30%-200%) then back to "Shrink To Fit" the preview looks fine!

Answer (score 0):

If I view the page with a hard refresh (ctrl + F5) and "Print Preview" the text size is incorrect and text is hidden. If I reload the same page (F5 only) and view "Print Preview" it works as expected. It seems like a caching issue in IE only.